# How to keep element centered while using jQuery UI resizable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

As you can see from the code below, the first "img" element is not centered because it uses jQuery UI resizable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
setTimeout(() => {      //"setTimeout()" runs only once! (Ensures that all required scripts are already loaded, especially when injecting this code in browsers!)
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "[Resize]" ).resizable({aspectRatio: true});
    $( "[Drag-Move]" ).draggable();
    });
}, "1000");     //1000 milliseconds = 1 second
</script>

<div style=" text-align: center !important; border:2px solid red; display:inline-block; color:red;"  Drag-Move>
<img width="50" style=" text-align: center !important;"  src="https://i.imgur.com/FHjzFv3.jpg"  Resize>
<p>Wonder Boss</p>
</div>

<div style=" text-align: center !important; border:2px solid red; display:inline-block; color:red;"  Drag-Move>
<img width="50" style=" text-align: center !important;"  src="https://i.imgur.com/FHjzFv3.jpg"  >
<p>Wonder Boss</p>
</div>
```

[Update]:

"jQuery UI Resizable" wraps "img" tags with "ui-wrapper" div, but it seems to be very bad coded since it changes the "img" tag position.

Another problem it causes, the "img" tag can't be properly moved inside its div container if "jQuery UI Draggable" is used.

"ui-wrapper" from "jQuery UI" source code:

```
this.element.wrap(
            $( "<div class='ui-wrapper'></div>" ).css( {
                overflow: "hidden",
                position: this.element.css( "position" ),
                width: this.element.outerWidth(),
                height: this.element.outerHeight(),
                top: this.element.css( "top" ),
                left: this.element.css( "left" )
            } )
        );
```

The best solution I found so far is to wrap "img" tag with a "div" tag as shown in code below (1 problem though, the div element can't fit its height correctly to the img element):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
setTimeout(() => {      //"setTimeout()" runs only once! (Ensures that all required scripts are already loaded, especially when injecting this code in browsers!)
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "[Resize]" ).resizable({aspectRatio: true});
    $( "[Drag-Move]" ).draggable();
    });
}, "1000");     //1000 milliseconds = 1 second
</script>

<div style=" text-align: center !important; border:2px solid red; display:inline-block; color:red; overflow:hidden;"  Drag-Move>
    <div style=" width:50px; border:2px solid green; display:inline-block;" resize Drag-Move>
    <img width="100%"  src="https://i.imgur.com/FHjzFv3.jpg"  >
    </div >
<p>Wonder Boss</p>
</div>

<div style=" text-align: center !important; border:2px solid red; display:inline-block; color:red;"  Drag-Move>
<img width="50" style=" text-align: center !important;"  src="https://i.imgur.com/FHjzFv3.jpg"  Drag-Move resize>
<p>Wonder Boss</p>
</div>
```

[Update]:

I found an acceptable solution. The code below is self explanatory. Better solutions are welcomed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
setTimeout(() => {      //"setTimeout()" runs only once! (Ensures that all required scripts are already loaded, especially when injecting this code in browsers!)
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "[Resize]" ).resizable({aspectRatio: true});
    $( "[Drag-Move]" ).draggable();
    });
}, "1000");     //1000 milliseconds = 1 second
</script>

<div style="text-align:center; border:2px solid red; display:inline-block; color:red; overflow:hidden;"  Resize Drag-Move>
    <div style="border:2px solid green; display:inline-block;" Drag-Move>
    <img width="50"  src="https://i.imgur.com/FHjzFv3.jpg" Resize>
    </div>
<p>Wonder Boss</p>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center; border:2px solid red; display:inline-block; color:red; overflow:hidden;"  Resize Drag-Move>
<img width="50"  src="https://i.imgur.com/FHjzFv3.jpg"  Resize Drag-Move>
<p>Wonder Boss</p>
</div>

<br><br>
- In order to preserve the "img" original position, it must be wrapped with an inline-block "div" tag <br><br>
- The "Resize" property must be placed in the "img" tag, not in the "div" tag <br><br>
- The "Drag-Move" property must be placed in the "div" tag, not in the "img" tag  <br><br>
- In this example, both the images (and their div containers) can be resized and moved! <br><br>
- Only the first image works as expected. <br><br>
```

Comment: Use css: `.ui-wrapper { margin: 0 auto !important; }`

Comment: @Behrouz , that indeed fixes the problem, but it causes another problem, elements that should be aligned left\right will be wrongly aligned to center.